# How do you describe waking up in the morning brain functioning slowly?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, idioms

Is there an adjective describing waking up in the morning and feeling slow, not able to remember stuff and think slowly?

Comment: That's called sleep inertia.

Comment: Sluggish is a good one: (see the second definition from Cambridge English Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sluggish)

Answer (score 3):

Consider ***groggy***
Defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/groggy) as:

> Dazed, weak, or unsteady, especially from illness, intoxication, sleep, or a blow.

“*She was still groggy from sleep*”

Answer (score 0):

Heard someone describe it as 'brain fog' recently and thought it accurate and descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

The usual description is - you are still "**half-asleep**".

I'm trying to type, but I'm ***half-asleep***.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/half-asleep